# Atlassian Stash - Branch level permission

Tags: git, bitbucket-server

We use Atlassian Stash.

I am admin of a Project. There is a repository in the project. I do not give any permission to anyone for the repository in the 'Repository level'.

There are 2 branches in the repository.  'master' and 'release/r30'.

I want my team members to commit their changes only in 'release/r30' branch.

So, In the Branch level permission, I select ''release/r30' and give permissions to my team members.

But - Stash is throwing an error like this **'remote: You have insufficient permissions to update'**

If i give the repository level permission write permission - it works fine. but i do not want this.

Am i doing anything wrong here?

Comment: Instead of granting permissions to the release branch, why not just take away permission from the master branch?

Comment: Thanks . but it wont help. Looks like I have to give permission to myself in the master, so that no one else can commit.

Comment: That's what I was trying to say (perhaps poorly), that you should just lock down the branch(es) you don't want people to commit to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ex-Stash developer here. From the docs:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/STASH/Using+branch+permissions

> Branch permissions are used to limit branch access to specific people who must still have write access to the project or repository.

Basically, the branch permissions work as a restriction over the normal repository write permission. Once you have write access you can restrict access via branch permissions.

Any reason why you don't want to give your team write access?